# quantity selection in html table to save per row to mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am fairly new to PHP and HTML, so I apologize for not quite being able to figure this out on my own. I also apologize if this idea is confusing. I'll try to explain it as best I can.

I am making a Discord bot that allows a tabletop card game to be played through Discord. This game involves making a deck of 40 cards (picking from hundreds of cards). To make a deck, players need to type a long comma-separated string of card names to the bot. To avoid this hassle for mobile users, I am making a website that displays all the cards, with a quantity selection for each row, so all mobile users need to do is select the quantity of the cards instead of typing them all out. Website displays like so... 
[image]

So, at this point, I'm a little stuck on where to go next. I'm not sure how to get each row's quantity/"Amount of Copies" selection to print out in a way it can be added to the database. I would like the format to be something like "Absorb, Absorb, Absorb, Ebb, Ebb, etc.. etc..." if the player intends on using 3 copies of "Absorb" and 2 copies of "Ebb". This would obviously be a list of 40 cards.

I have the data placed into the table via a php while loop. The DiscordID and Kitname fields are saving correctly. The Quantity dropdowns are appropriately displaying 0 to 3 for options. I'm just unsure how to bind the cardname to the quantity for that row.

Here's the code for index.php

```
<html>
<body>
<head>Make a kit for Bakugan Generations on Discord
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"
    integrity="sha256-BTlTdQO9/fascB1drekrDVkaKd9PkwBymMlHOiG+qLI="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">

DiscordID: <input type="text" name="discordID" required/><br><br>
Kitname: <input type="text" name="kitname" required/><br><br>

<table id="cards" class="display" style="width:100%" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Number of Copies</th>
        <th>Card Number</th>
        <th>Card Set</th>
        <th>Cardname</th>
        <th>Energy Cost</th>
        <th>Faction</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Power</th>
        <th>Damage</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Core 1</th>
        <th>Core 2</th>
        <th>Base Bakugan</th>
        <th>Rarity</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php

    $host= "localhost";
    $user= "root";
    $pass= "";
    $db= "cards";

    $dbconnect = new mysqli("$host", "$user", "$pass", "$db");

    if ($dbconnect->connect_error) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . $dbconnect->connect_error);
    }

        $query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SELECT * FROM cardsmaster")
            or die(mysqli_error($dbconnect));

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo
                "<tr>
                <td><select>  
                    <option value='0'>0</option>  
                    <option value='1'>1</option>  
                    <option value='2'>2</option>  
                    <option value='3'>3</option>   
                </select></td>
                <td>{$row['card_number']}</td>
                <td>{$row['cardset']}</td>
                <td>{$row['card_name']}</td>
                <td>{$row['energy_cost']}</td>
                <td>{$row['faction']}</td>
                <td>{$row['type']}</td>
                <td>{$row['power']}</td>
                <td>{$row['damage']}</td>
                <td>{$row['text']}</td>
                <td>{$row['core_1']}</td>
                <td>{$row['core_2']}</td>
                <td>{$row['base_bakugan']}</td>
                <td>{$row['rarity']}</td>
                </tr>";
            }

            ?>
            </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" />

</form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#cards').DataTable();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the code for insert.php

```
<?php

$discordID = $_POST['discordID'];
$kitname = $_POST['kitname'];


    $host= "localhost";
    $user= "root";
    $pass= "";
    $db= "test";

    $conn = new mysqli("$host", "$user", "$pass", "$db");

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
          }else {
            $INSERT = "INSERT INTO demo (discordID, kitname) VALUES (?, ?)";

            //statement
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $discordID, $kitname);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "New record inserted successfully!";
          } 
?>
```

I have replaced the login credentials with the root and blank password, but rest assured I have made another account to access the database. I am using Wamp64 to display everything on localhost for now, mySQL/phpmyadmin for the database.

Eventually, I would like a list of currently selected cards to appear at the bottom of the page in order to display all the cards currently selected, and what the current card count is (AJAX?).

I'm just unsure where to go next. I have searched around and didn't find much that seemed to help guide me in some direction.

Thanks in advance for any advice and guidance!

Comment: You need to give your `<select>` a name attribute, probably best to use the `$row['card_name']` variable. Then each row will appear in your $_POST and you can do something with it there.

Comment: @Mark Okay, so I set `<select name='$row[card_name]QTY'>` then inside the insert.php file I put `$cards = $_POST['$row[card_name]QTY'];` but results in an unidentified index error. Do I need to do another SELECT query and loop inside the insert.php file as well to get the index or is there a different way to do that?

Comment: Set your select like `<select name='$row['card_name']'>`. Then in insert.php do a `print_r($_POST)` and see what you get.

Comment: @Mark When it put `<select name='$row['card_name']'>` I was getting a syntax error. I ended up fixing that with `$cardname = 'card_name';` right before the echo in the loop and changing the select name to `<select name='$row[$cardname]'>` I also did the `print_r($_POST)` as you said and now it is showing this [link](https://i.gyazo.com/bf81730d25948c23dd45eac7bcb50bf7.png) which is a step in the right direction, as it shows the 3 quantity in the right spot for the drop down I chose. But how would I make just the `$row[card_name]QTY` name as a variable in insert.php?